# How to remove background Noise in Audio Track?

Tags: android, media, audio-streaming, audio-recording, audiotrack

I am developing `VOIP` kind of application. Sending the voice is perfect but when i receive the same voice from the webserver, i am playing back that using `AudioTrack` API.

I am calling `at.play()` and `at.write` in a Thread so that i should get all the voice which is recorded and sent from the other device.

But, now the problem here i m facing is, if there is no voice than its still playing like some bullet sound, i mean there is a continuos background sound when i try to play .

I m using this following function in a Thread:

```
                   if (at != null) {
                        if (at.getPlayState() != AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING) {
                            at.play();
                   } else {
                       if (playing == true) {
                                System.out.println("BEFORE WRITE");
                                at.write(playShortData, 0,
                                        playShortData.length);
                                System.out.println("AFTER WRITE");

                                at.flush();
                                playing = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

How can i remove the background noise if there no voice is send from other device.

Comment: You should do some signal processing. It's usually done using Android NDK: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: @sinisha, i dont want to use any NDK... I just wanted to use Existing API's to work

Comment: @sinisha, In my another application, there is no background noise and i m using same AUdiotrack there also ...

Comment: Are you sure there isn't problem during recording?

Comment: Yeah i m 100% sure....because before sending it to server, i m storing that it into a sd card and playing externally... it was playing fine with no issues

Comment: What recording source are you using?  Some source is optimized for voice recording, which includes some DSP for compression and gates.  A gate is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its playing Junk value when none of them is speaking on other sides, its just sending junk values ..

Comment: so what is the solution?